# Get all files but the files in array - Bash

Tags: shell-script

I am required to write a one-time util that does some operation on all the files in a given directory but a list of files in a predefined list. Since the given list is predefined, I am going to hard-code it as an array.

Having said that, how to get names of all files that are not in the given array? This can be in any standard unix script(bash, awk, perl).

Comment: Note that `bash` is not standard in unix. The standard Unix shell has no support for arrays except `"$@"` (though most Unices have one or more shells like (t)csh, ksh, zsh or bash with array support)

Comment: Similar: [Bash - How to find all files NOT in array](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/354419)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `bash`, you could do:

```
all=(*)
except=(file1 file2 notme.txt)
only=()
IFS=/
for file in "${all[@]}"; do
  case "/${except[*]}/" in
    (*"/$file/"*) ;;     # do nothing (exclude)
    (*) only+=("$file")  # add to the array
  esac
done
ls -ld -- "${only[@]}"
```

(that works here for the files in the current directory, but not reliably for globs like `all=(*/*) except=(foo/bar)` as we use `/` to join the elements of the array for the look-up).

It's based on the fact that `"${array[*]}"` joins the elements of the array with the first character of `$IFS` (here chosen to be `/` as it can't otherwise occur in a file *name*; NUL is a character that can't occur in a file *path*, but unfortunately `bash` (contrary to `zsh`) can't have such a character in its variables). So for each file in `$all` (here with `$file` being `foo` as an example), we do a `case "/file1/file2/notme.txt/" in (*"/foo/"*)` to check if `$file` is to be excluded.

Comment: Hi @Stéphane, That works awesome. I am just trying to find out explantion for the statements using *. It would be helpful If you add it.

Comment: I need details about 2 more fact using *. The statement (*"/$i/"*) and (*) only+=("$i") . I am also parallelly trying to find it as well.

Comment: @Kannan, is it clearer after this new edit?

Comment: any reason not to use `find` with `! -name foo`s (followed by an appropriate `-exec`)?

Comment: @Kevin, that's getting away from the original question. Also, `-name` takes a wildcard pattern, not file name, so you'd need to escape the wildcard operators.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I tried myself, but still unable to get how (\*"/$file/"\*)  matches "/${except[*]}/" . Trying still...

Answer (score 5):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
except=(file1 file2 notme.txt)
all=(*)
only=(${all:|except})
ls -ld -- $only
```

Mnemonic for `${all:|except}`: elements of `$all` *bar* those of `$except`.

You can also check if files are in the `$except` array as part of a *glob qualifier*:

```
ls -ld -- *.txt(^e:'((except[(Ie)$REPLY]))':)
```

Or using a function:

```
in_except() ((except[(Ie)${1-$REPLY}]))
ls -ld -- *.txt(^+in_except)
```

Comment: zsh is not available for us to use.

Answer (score 3):

If the filenames are simple enough, you could use [bash's `GLOBIGNORE` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion):

> The `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable may be used to restrict the set of
>   filenames matching a pattern. If `GLOBIGNORE` is set, each matching
>   filename that also matches one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is
>   removed from the list of matches. If the `nocaseglob` option is set,
>   the matching against the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is performed without
>   regard to case. The filenames `.` and `..` are always ignored when
>   `GLOBIGNORE` is set and not null. However, setting `GLOBIGNORE` to a
>   non-null value has the effect of enabling the `dotglob` shell option,
>   so all other filenames beginning with a ‘`.`’ will match. To get the
>   old behavior of ignoring filenames beginning with a ‘`.`’, make ‘`.*`’
>   one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE`. The `dotglob` option is disabled
>   when `GLOBIGNORE` is unset.

```
$ echo *
bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 lost+found mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
$ except=(etc lib lib64 tmp sbin)
$ GLOBIGNORE=$(IFS=:; printf "%s" "${except[*]}")
$ echo *
bin boot dev home lost+found mnt opt proc root run srv sys usr var
```

Of course, if you're creating the array, then you could directly set the `GLOBIGNORE` variable instead:

```
GLOBIGNORE=etc:lib:lib64:tmp:sbin
```

You can also take advantage of any patterns there might be in the list that fit bash wildcards:

```
GLOBIGNORE=etc:lib*:tmp:sbin
```

Comment: It looks like you can escape `:`, `?`, `*`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`and backslash with backslash in GLOBIGNORE. So it looks like you should be able to construct a GLOBIGNORE for arbitrary array elements by doing the proper escaping before joining the elements.

Comment: Beware that having `GLOBIGNORE=.*` means that `./*` globs will fail to match and that `dir/*` will still include hidden file. That part of the manual is misleading. You don't want to have `.*` in GLOBIGNORE. Generally, GLOBIGNORE is quite useless in `bash` (compare with `ksh`'s `FIGNORE`), but it looks like you've found one usage for it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas pity `**` doesn't work in GLOBIGNORE, it would have been interesting then.

Comment: It's not needed. GLOBIGNORE is a pattern that is matched on the full glob expansion in the end, so `*/foo` will exclude `x/foo` and `x/y/z/foo` just the same (it works like the `~` operator in `zsh`, you can get `bash`'s GLOBIGNORE behaviour in `zsh` by appending `~$~GLOBIGNORE` to your globs there). If you wanted to exclude `x/foo` only, you'd need `*([^/])/foo` (`./x/foo` would still be matched by `./**/foo` though).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it does? I tested `GLOBIGNORE=*/.git*` in a directory with a bunch of git repos in it, and for `printf "%s\n" c*/* ./c*/* | grep git`, I got `./cassandra/.git`, `./certbot/.gitignore`, etc. in the output, but *not* `cassandra/.git` or the like.

Comment: I can't reproduce with 4.3 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I can on `4.4.12(1)-release` on Arch Linux, but you're right, I can't repro on Ubuntu 16.04's bash 4.3 either.

Comment: confirmed with 4.4.12 on Debian. the NEWS file doesn't mention any change in that area. I'll dig a bit more.